# C++ : can't insert node in linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Why my code can't run, what is this because of the parameters? please help with the correct syntax

I am still learning about linked lists in C++

This is the error

[image: Image : this is the program image and the error]

Comment: Post your code and errors as _text_, not images.  See [ask].

Comment: You're missing braces.

Comment: That isn't "the error" that is a *bunch* of different errors. Most of them are because of a misplaced `}`. Even fixing that I doubt this does what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem isn't that you're still learning about linked lists in c++, it's that you're still learning c++.

a line like #107:

```
while(after->dataList != x);
```

doesn't do anything - because the only thing it's asked to do is the empty statement:

```
;
```

You should consider adding braces around blocks of code that are supposed to run together, like:

```
while (after->dataList != x) // NO semi-colon
{
    // some code
}
```

or

```
do 
{
    // some code that changes x or y
} while ( x < y );
```

those braces are important in c++, c, java, javascript etc.  If you get them wrong the compiler has no idea what you're trying to do.  `{` opens a block of code and `}` ends it.